# Correct sorting of composite page numbers with makeindex

Tags: indexing, sorting

Running an index file like

```
\indexentry{foo}{1}
\indexentry{foo}{i}
\indexentry{foo}{a}
```

through `makeindex` results in an includable output file like

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item foo, i, 1, a

\end{theindex}
```

Apparently, `i` is considered a roman number, which is usually correct.

However, when the page numbers are composite as in

```
\indexentry{foo}{1.7}
\indexentry{foo}{i.8}
\indexentry{foo}{a.9}
```

with style file

```
page_compositor "."
```

I get an output of

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item foo, 1.7, a.9, i.8

\end{theindex}
```

Now, `i` is considered a letter, which is wrong in my use case.

Is there a way to tell `makeindex` when a letter is a roman number, particularly in the composite case above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not find a detailed description of the rules, I had a look at the source of `makeindex`. The heuristic that is applied in `scanid.c`, function `int scan_no(char no[], short npg[], short *count, short *type)` is the following: a single letter from i,v,x,l,c,d,m that is not followed by a `page_compositor` (as set in the `makeindex` style file) is a roman number, as well as string of two or more roman figures. So "vi.1" and "A.i" contain a roman number, while "i.1" does not.

It also can be seen that alphabetic page labels are restricted to one letter, which means that a page label "ij" is invalid, while "ji" and "jj" are accepted and considered to be the same. Funnily, also "ji.1" and "jj.2" are considered to be the same, but not "j.1" and "j.2". Just one more reason to switch to a `xindy` based indexing solution.

All this is hard-coded into `makeindex`, which means that one can either modify the source itself, use `xindy`, or resort to something like DavidCarlisle's solution, which is a pain in the `\@empty\relax` when the indexing commands are used indirectly, e.g., via the `glossaries` package.

Answer (score 5):

I thought there was a flag to force `i` to be roman, but I don't see it now so...

If you arrange your `idx` file to look like

```
\indexentry{foo|zz}{1.1.7}
\indexentry{foo|zz}{0.1.8}
\indexentry{foo|zz}{0.4.8}
\indexentry{foo|zz}{0.5.8}
\indexentry{foo|zz}{1.a.9}
```

with an extra prefix component `0.` for the roman initial pages and `1.` for the rest and write all the pages using the arabic digits, then `makeindex` sorts correctly and produces

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item foo, \zz{0.1.8}, \zz{0.4.8}, \zz{0.5.8}, \zz{1.1.7}, \zz{1.a.9}

\end{theindex}
```

Then you just need to define `\zz` to put things right, discarding the first component of each number but using the Roman form of the second component if the first component is 0

```
\def\zz#1{\zzz#1}
\def\zzz#1.#2.{\ifnum#1=0 \romannumeral\fi#2\relax}
```